# What Form should I create to display these models?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm brand new to Django and I'm trying to create a simple web, so sorry if this seems quite trivial or simple. Currently I have these models:

```
class Fighter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rating = models.DecimalField(default=1600, max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    url = models.URLField(default='')

class Fight(models.Model):
    member1 = models.ForeignKey(Fighter, related_name='fighter_1')
    member2 = models.ForeignKey(Fighter, related_name='fighter_2')
```

I want to display a random fight and it's associated members every time I refresh the page, and then have a radio button (or something similar) that allows a user to choose who they think would win.

I think I need to use forms to do this, but after reading lots of Django documentation I have no idea about how to do this. Could someone please explain the best way for me to go about this!

I have been using class based views, is this the correct thing to do? If I haven't included enough code then please let me know.

Comment: You haven't really explained what you're doing with the results from that radio button, and how that relates to the "rating" value in Fighter.

Comment: My plan is to use the ELO rating system, but I just wanted to get it displaying properly first. I'm really struggling with how I go about using forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep track of which fight instance is being referred to, I have used the URL to mention the fight id. A new fight instance will be created each time the user visits the (home) page. Then the view will redirect to the URL for that fight's form.

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from fights.views import FightView, random_fight

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', random_fight, name='home'),
    url(r'^fight/(?P<fight_id>\d+)/$', FightView.as_view(), name='fight_view'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

#### forms.py

The form will be initialized with a dynamically created radio box with the names of fighters passed as a keyword argument.

```
from django import forms
from .models import Fighter


class FighterSelectForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        choices = kwargs.pop("choices", [])
        super(FighterSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["fighter_choices"] = forms.ChoiceField(
            widget=forms.RadioSelect,
            choices=choices)
```

#### views.py

`random_fight()` creates a new `Fight` instance with two random `Fighter` members and redirects to the corresponding `fight_view`. `FightView` class overrides the `get_form()` function to pass the fighter names from the Fight object, which is in turn derived from the URL.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Fight, Fighter
from .forms import FighterSelectForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView


def random_fight(request):
    fighters = Fighter.objects.order_by("?")[:2]
    fight = Fight.objects.create(member1=fighters[0], member2=fighters[1])
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('fight_view', kwargs={"fight_id": str(fight.id)}))


class FightView(FormView):
    template_name = 'fight.html'
    success_url = '/thanks/'    # Not defined here

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        fight = Fight.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get("fight_id"))
        choices = [(fight.member1.id, fight.member1.name),
                   (fight.member2.id, fight.member2.name)]
        kwargs = super(FightView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({"choices": choices})
        form = FighterSelectForm(**kwargs)
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        selected = Fighter.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['fighter_choices'])
        selected.rating += 100  # Use any logic to change rating here
        selected.save()
        print("Fighter selected: {}".format(selected.name))
        return super(FightView, self).form_valid(form)
```

#### fight.html

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: My plan is to change the `rating` of each `Fighter` based on the users choice. Is creating a new model still the best way to do this?

Comment: Don't you want to keep a record of what a user rated?

Comment: No, the user will select a `Fighter` and I will write a function that updates both ratings accordingly

Comment: I see. In that case, you can add a `FormView` and you should be done.

Comment: It was creating the correct Form that I was struggling with, sorry if the original question wasn't clear!

Comment: Have modified the answer to describe all the associated code now.